# Looping sets of numbers at a set interval within multiple If functions

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm trying to create scoring system that allows me to populate a set of "Scores" over a set number of years, for example 100 years. As shown in the image above.

Depending on the "Type" of material (i.e. Light, Moderate or Heavy), over the 100 years the material (i.e Rubber) will deteriorate from 1 to 4, and be replaced with a new rubber when it reaches 4 and then then score becomes 1 again and repeats until 100 years.

So first my function would have three "IF" functions to identify the cells that contain "Rubber" , "Type" and the "Initial" score.

I have completed the above using IF, THEN functions. I'm now stuck with the part which follows.

Now take the "Initial Score 2" as example:
If the "Rubber" is "Light" and it has an initial condition score of "2", then fill in the rows (with 2 spacings between each score) the score '2' 9x, score '3' 4x and score '1' 20x, and loop this for 100 times.

I'm looking for a way to begin populating from where the function is called from.

My attempt so far:

```
Function score(TYP, COND, INI, i As Integer) 


    If TYP = "Rubber" Then 
        Goto 10 
    ElseIf TYP = "Wood" Then 
        Goto 20 
    ElseIf TYP = "Metal" Then 
        Goto 30 


        10 'Severity and Extent


        If COND = "Light" Then 
            Goto 11 
        ElseIf COND = "Moderate" Then 
            Goto 12 
        ElseIf COND = "Heavy" Then 
            Goto 13 

            11 'Populate  Scores
            If INI = "1" Then 


                For i = 1 To 40 Step 4 
                    Cells(1, i).Value = 1 
                Next 


                For i = 1 To 10 Step 4 
                    Cells(1, i + 40).Value = 2 


                Next 
            End Function
```

Comment: if you're going to change cell values like this `Cells(1, i).Value = 1`, consider about using `Sub` instead `Function`

Comment: it seems like something is missing here. where/how do you work out the rubber type and what are different rubber types multipliers

Comment: @simoco I'm trying not to use a Sub for convenience purpose. Therefore  I'm trying to replace the  Cells(1, i + 40).Value = 1 with something that works within a function.

Comment: @mehow The Rubber type and condition are all predefined constants.

Comment: Best practice is to have a function return a value and not change anything else... Why would you *not* want to use a Sub?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function instead `Cells(1, i).Value = 1`:

```
Function ChangeAnotherCell(rCell As Range, vVal) As String
   Application.Volatile
   With rCell
      If CStr(.Value) = "" Then
         .Replace "", vVal, 1, , 0
      Else
         .Replace .Value, vVal, 1, , 0
      End If
   End With
   ChangeAnotherCell = rCell.Value
End Function
```

You can use it, for example, like this:

```
For i = 1 To 40 Step 4 
   newCellValue = ChangeAnotherCell(Cells(1, i), 1)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks @simoco it's kind of working with some glitches. The numbers doesn't populate when everything is empty.~

Is there a way to make the number appear from where the function is called?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to use now. (for me, it works fine even in case empty cells)

Comment: Thanks for the update @simoco. Is there a way for the numbers to start populating from where the function is called?

At the moment if you start a fresh sheet and call the function from cell (2,1) only the first number will appear on the first line, unless you fill in some cells further down the line.

Comment: this method is unstable. So, the only way I've found to get it work with your function - is to select all cells that you are going to use, prepolulate them with some value by entering for example "1" in some cell and pushing CTRL+ENTER, and then clean this cells. After these manipulations, function behaves stable

Comment: Many thanks for your help! 
Do you know if there is a function or a way of reference that could change (Cells(1,i)) to refer to the cell where the function was called from?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding (I'm not a native English speaker:) Do you mean something like `ActiveCell`? For example if you call the function from `B10` cell, then `ActiveCell` will refer exactly to `B10` cell:)